# Java error api level method

Tags: java, android, api, runtime-error

I get an error

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.app.Activity.isDestroyed

It has something to do with only running on devices which are api 17 or higher, is there anyway around this?

```
       private WeakReference<Activity> mActivityRef;

    @Override
        public void onFinish() {

            Activity activity = mActivityRef.get();
//            if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
//do your thing!

                if (activity != null && !activity.isFinishing() && !activity.isDestroyed()) {
                    activity.startActivity(new Intent(activity, ListOfAlarms.class));
                    activity.finish();
                }
                mStarted = false;

//            }
//            Intent goBack = new Intent(CountDownAct.this, ListOfAlarms.class);
//            startActivity(goBack);
//            finish();
        }
```

Comment: What is your Manifest.xml configuration? It seems you are running code on unsupported versions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This API was added only in API Level 17 [Check this!](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#isDestroyed%28%29)

To avoid the crash, you can verify with the following code

```
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1){
//do your thing!
}
```

To get it working on lower API levels, you can create your own BaseActivity.java and add code like this

```
public class BaseActivity extends Activity {
    private boolean mDestroyed;

    public boolean isDestroyed(){
        return mDestroyed;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        mDestroyed = true;
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

Now, make all your activities extend this BaseActivity as follows

```
public class MainActivity extends BaseActivity {
...
}
```

**EDIT** (After OP added code snippets)

First create a `BaseActivity.java` file as I have shown above.
Then, make all your activities extend `BaseActivity` instead of `Activity`.

Now, change

```
private WeakReference<Activity> mActivityRef;
```

to

```
private WeakReference<BaseActivity> mActivityRef;
```

And change

```
Activity activity = mActivityRef.get();
```

to

```
BaseActivity activity = mActivityRef.get();
```

Comment: How would I implement that in this though, I attached a code snippet

Comment: What is the `activity` object here referring to? Can you paste the part of the code where you assign the `activity` object.